# SharePoint: Is it possible to have a field value returned from a column in another list?

Tags: sharepoint

I am not a programmer though so I need it to be done in SharePoint as a function please.

So if List A has column 1 value Michael, I want List A column 2 to return a value from List B that has an item with a column 1 value of Michael.

Is this possible?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

**It is possible.** Unfortunately, what you seek is not something that can be done without any manner of programming. Basically, your goal is that List A Column 2 is a Lookup column that references a specific value on List B. This itself is simple enough, just create a Lookup Column that references said value on List B.

To make it specifically grab the List B item whose Column 1 value is the same as the Column 1 value on the List A item, that is what will require some amount of code. Be it an Event Handler, or maybe you could set up a workflow with SharePoint Designer (I'm hesitant about that but I imagine it should be possible to some degree). It is not that difficult of a code and I can provide you some basic instructions to set it up if you wish to go down the programming route.